# Part accessibility to exposed/public APIs and rest public APIs are not accessible

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cognito

dependencies which I am using are:

```
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-sdk-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cognitoidp</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.641</version>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=9002
spring.application.name=identity-provider

# AWS Cognito Configurations
aws.cognito.user-pool-id=pool_id
aws.cognito.client-id=client_id
aws.cognito.client-secret=client_Secret
aws.region=region

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-id=${aws.cognito.client-id}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-secret=${aws.cognito.client-secret}
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.client-name=AWS Cognito
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cognito.scope=openid,phone,email,profile
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.cognito.issuer-uri=https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_rrtfXfje7
```

cognito-client:

in cognito client, I am using few variables like:

```
    @Value("${aws.cognito.client-id}")
    private String clientId = client_id;
    @Value("${@Value("${aws.cognito.client-id}")}")
    private  String userPool = user_pool;
    @Value("${aws.cognito.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret = client-secret;
```

due to some issues these values are not able to read from application.properties file. please help me.

cognito-client:

```
@Configuration
public class CognitoClient {

    private final AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client = createCognitoClient();
    private String clientId = client_id;;
    private  String userPool = user_pool";
    private String clientSecret = client-secret;




    public AWSCognitoIdentityProvider createCognitoClient(){
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(client_id,clientSecret);
        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
        return AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
    }

    public SignUpResult  signUp(String fullName,
                                String username,
                                String password,
                                String email,
                                String userType){

        SignUpRequest request = new SignUpRequest()
                .withSecretHash(generateSecretHash(clientId,clientSecret,username))
                .withUserAttributes(new AttributeType().withName("email").withValue(email)
                        )
                .withClientId(clientId).withUsername(username).withPassword(password);


        SignUpResult result = client.signUp(request);
        return result;
    }

    public ConfirmSignUpResult confirmSignUpResult(String username,
                                                   String confirmCode){

        ConfirmSignUpRequest request = new ConfirmSignUpRequest()
                .withSecretHash(generateSecretHash(clientId,clientSecret,username))
                .withClientId(clientId).withUsername(username).withConfirmationCode(confirmCode);
        ConfirmSignUpResult result = client.confirmSignUp(request);
        return result;
    }

    public ResendConfirmationCodeResult resendConfirmationCodeResult(String username){
        ResendConfirmationCodeRequest request = new ResendConfirmationCodeRequest()
                .withClientId(clientId)
                .withUsername(username)
                .withSecretHash(generateSecretHash(clientId,clientSecret,username));
        ResendConfirmationCodeResult result = client.resendConfirmationCode(request);
        return result;
    }

    public Map<String,String> login(String username,String password){

        Map<String,String> authParameter = new LinkedHashMap<>(){{
            put("username",username);
            put("password",password);
        }};

        AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest()
                .withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)
                .withUserPoolId(userPool)
                .withClientId(clientId)
                .withAuthParameters(authParameter);
        AdminInitiateAuthResult authResult = client.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);
        AuthenticationResultType resultType = authResult.getAuthenticationResult();
        return new LinkedHashMap<String,String>(){{
            put("idToken",resultType.getIdToken());
            put("accessToken",resultType.getAccessToken());
            put("refreshToken",resultType.getRefreshToken());
        }};
    }


    private static String generateSecretHash(String userPoolClientId, String userPoolClientSecret, String userName) {
        final String HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA256";

        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
                userPoolClientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
            mac.init(signingKey);
            mac.update(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(userPoolClientId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawHmac);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while calculating ");
        }
    }
}
```

in above I had to hard code the values of the variables, which I don't find a good practice. I seek your help in this to figure out why I am not able to read values from application.properties.

controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/idp-auth/public")
public class IdpPublicController {

    @Autowired
    private AwsCognitoServices services;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public Response signupApi(@RequestBody JsonNode signupObject){
        String fullName = signupObject.get("fullName").asText();
        String username = signupObject.get("username").asText();
        String email = signupObject.get("email").asText();
        String password = signupObject.get("password").asText();
        String userType = signupObject.get("userType").asText();

        return services.signUp(fullName,username,password,email,userType);
    }

    @PostMapping("/confirm-signup")
    public Response confirmSignupApi(@RequestBody JsonNode confirmSignupObject){
        String confirmCode = confirmSignupObject.get("confirmCode").asText();
        String username = confirmSignupObject.get("username").asText();

        return services.confirmSignup(username,confirmCode);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public Response login(@RequestBody JsonNode loginObject){
        String username = loginObject.get("username").asText();
        String password = loginObject.get("password").asText();

        return services.login(username,password);
    }
    @PostMapping("/resend-confirm-code")
    public Response resendConfirmCode(@RequestBody JsonNode resendConfirmCode){
        String username = resendConfirmCode.get("username").asText();
        return services.resendConfirmCode(username);
    }
}
```

security-config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    public SecurityConfiguration(CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler){
        this.customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler= new CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity.csrf(httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer -> httpSecurityCsrfConfigurer.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests->
                requests.requestMatchers("/idp-auth/public/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/idp-auth/private/**").authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(oauth->
                        oauth.redirectionEndpoint(endpoint-> endpoint.baseUri("/login/oauth2/code/cognito"))
                                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpointConfig -> userInfoEndpointConfig.userAuthoritiesMapper(userAuthoritiesMapper()))
                                .successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/"));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public GrantedAuthoritiesMapper userAuthoritiesMapper() {
        return (authorities) -> {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

            try {
                OidcUserAuthority oidcUserAuthority = (OidcUserAuthority) new ArrayList<>(authorities).get(0);

                mappedAuthorities = ((ArrayList<?>) oidcUserAuthority.getAttributes().get("cognito:groups")).stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Not Authorized!");

                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }

            return mappedAuthorities;
        };
    }
}
```

CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler:

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        for(GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()){
            DefaultOidcUser defaultOidcUser = (DefaultOidcUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            Map<String, Object> userAttributes = defaultOidcUser.getAttributes();
            System.out.println(userAttributes);

        }

    }
}
```

my main and final question is that why I am only able to access signup api without authentication/ redirect callback uri being called . i.e. no authentication needed to call signup API but the moment I call other APIs authentication/ callback uri is called. i.e. authentication needed (hosted ui for login and signup by cognito) is shown . Any help would be appreciated.